# How do I use CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet with a serviceBean instead of a serviceClass?

Tags: jetty, cxf, jax-rs, embedded-jetty

I am trying to use Apache CXF with JAX-RS to serve as an embedded REST endpoint within a larger application.  I cannot use spring configured CXF because my application needs to  manage the lifecycle of the Jetty instance and servlets.

The example [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html#JAXRSServicesConfiguration-AttachingJAXRSendpointstoanexistingJettyserver) shows how to do this with a service class name, but in my application it will be roundabout and ugly to pass a classname rather than a bean.  Can anyone point me toward a way to use a bean here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to leave **CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet** create your instance, but you can configure it (=bind it to outside world) by extending **CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet#configureSingleton**

Answer (score 0):

See this post: [CXF/Jetty equivalent of the following Jersey/Jetty code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28010695/cxf-jetty-equivalent-of-the-following-jersey-jetty-code) for a solution. Tested with CXF 3.0.3 and Jety 9.2.5.v20141112.

Answer (score -1):

This is how it's done

```
Object serviceObject = // your JAX-RS service object
JAXRSServerFactoryBean rs = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
rs.setServiceBeanObjects(serviceObject);
Server server = rs.create();
```

Comment: This piece of code creates a server.
@Brandon says explicitely he wants to use CXFNonSpringJAXRSServlet for embedding in exisitng Jetty.